# How do i prevent redirection to the first tab from second tab on refresh or form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, tabs

```
<ul class="tabrow" role="tablist" id="myTab">
<li <?php echo in_array($dashboard_type,array('buyerproj','oldproj'))?'class="selected"':' '?>  ><a href="#buyer">BUYER</a></li>
<li  <?php echo in_array($dashboard_type,array('message','ongoing','acceptpro','decpro'))?'class="selected"':' '?> ><a href="#writer">WRITER</a></li>   <!--/*?'selected':' ' Removed: was affecting layout*/-->
</ul>
<div class="tab padding-bottom-181">
    <div class="tab-content" id="buyer"  <?php echo in_array($dashboard_type,array('buyerproj','oldproj'))?'selected':'display-none'?>
        <div class="col-md-10 div-center text-center"><span class="float-left align-middle"><p class="dash-small-text margin-bottom-none">YOUR</p><h3 

class="margin-top-none float-left">Current <br/>Balance</h3><p class="dash-small-text float-right margin-top-40 margin-left-min">IS</p></span><h2 class="margin-left-min text-blue float-left align-middle big-text margin-top-20">$<?php echo number_format($currentBalance); ?></h2>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('money/add')?>" class="btn-blue btn-small add-money margin-top-35">Add Money</a><span>
            <a href="#"><img id="library1" src="<?php echo site_url('img/Transactions.png') ?>"></a></span>
        </div>
            <div class="text-center txt-green"><?php echo  validation_errors(); ?>
            <?php echo  $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?>
            </div>
        <h5 class="text-center background-yellow">PROJECTS POSTED (<?php echo count($buyerprojects_count)?>)</h5>
                <ul class="tabs-menu1 div-center" role="tablist">
                    <li class="<?php echo $dashboard_type=='buyerproj'?'current1':' '?>  <?php echo !in_array($dashboard_type,array('buyerproj','oldproj'))?'current1':''?>"><a href="#tab-1">Current Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php echo $dashboard_type=='oldproj'?'current1':' '?>"><a href="#tab-2">Older Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
    <div class="tab padding-bottom-181">

        <div class="tab-content1 <?php echo $dashboard_type=='buyerproj'?'current1':' '?>" id="tab-1"> <!--current projects -->
            <div class="div-center table-responsive padding-side-19 padding-bottom-100">

                <table class="table table-bordered padding-bottom-20 background-4-tablist">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="row text-center">
                        <th class="padding-left-9">DATE</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="padding-left-9">TOPIC</th>
                        <th class="padding-left-9">SUBMISSIONS</th>
                        <th class="text-center">VIEW</th>
                        <!--<th class="text-center">EDIT PROJECT</th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php if($buyerprojects == null) 
                            echo "<tr class='text-center'> <td class=text-center style=background-color:#fedd76; colspan=10 >No current projects </td><tr>";  
                        else
                        foreach($buyerprojects as $project){?> 
                        <tr class="row text-center">
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1"><?php echo flip_date(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($project->p_submitdate))); ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 info_1 text-center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('project/view_project2/'.$project->p_id)?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#baseModal-med" data-backdrop="static"><img src="<?php echo site_url('img/edit.png') ?>"></a></td>
                        <td class="col-md-6 info_1"><?php echo $project->p_title ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1"><?php echo $project->submissions ?>
                        <?php if ($project->submissions > 0 &&  $project->notific > 0) {?>
                        <span class="uc-notifications-bell__count1 js-uc-notifications-bell-count animated infinite pulse"><?php echo $project->notific; ?> New</span>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <span></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1 text-center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('project/view_submission/'.$project->p_id)?>"  ><img src="<?php echo site_url('img/eye.png') ?>"></a></td>

                    <!--    <td class="col-md-2 info text-center"><a href="<?php //echo site_url('addproject/index/'.$project->p_id)?>"><img src="<?php //echo site_url('img/edit.png') ?>"></a></td> -->
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>
                </table><?php echo $links2; ?>
                <button class="btn-orange float-right margin-top-30" onclick="window.location.href='addproject'">add project</button>
            </div>
        </div> <!--current projects -->

        <div class="tab-content1 display-none <?php echo $dashboard_type=='oldproj'?'current1':' '?>" id="tab-2"> <!--older projects -->        
            <div class="div-center table-responsive padding-side-19 padding-bottom-100 margin-top-30">

                <table class="table table-bordered padding-bottom-20 background-4-tablist">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="row text-center">
                        <th class="padding-left-9">DATE</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="padding-left-9">TOPIC</th>
                        <th class="padding-left-9">SUBMISSIONS</th>
                        <th class="text-center">VIEW</th>
                        <!--<th class="text-center">EDIT PROJECT</th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>     
                        <?php if($oldprojects == null) 
                            echo "<tr class='text-center'> <td class=text-center style=background-color:#fedd76; colspan=10 >No older projects </td><tr>";  
                        else?>                      
                        <?php foreach($oldprojects as $project){ ?>
                        <tr class="row text-center">
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1"><?php echo flip_date(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($project->p_submitdate))); ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 info_1 text-center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('project/view_project2/'.$project->p_id)?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#baseModal-med" data-backdrop="static"><img src="<?php echo site_url('img/edit.png') ?>"></a></td>
                        <td class="col-md-6 info_1"><?php echo $project->p_title ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1"><?php echo $project->submissions ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 info_1 text-center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('project/view_submission/'.$project->p_id)?>"  ><img src="<?php echo site_url('img/eye.png') ?>"></a></td>
                        <!--<td class="col-md-2 info text-center"><a href="<?php //echo //site_url('addproject/index/'.$project->p_id)?>"><img src="<?php //echo//site_url('img/edit.png') ?>"></a></td>-->
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                </table><?php echo $links; ?>
                <button class="btn-orange float-right margin-top-30" onclick="window.location.href='addproject'">add project</button>
            </div>
        </div>  <!--older projects -->


    </div>  <!-- tab content -->

</div> <!-- buyer -->

<div class="tab-content <?php echo in_array($dashboard_type,array('message','ongoing','acceptpro','decpro'))?'selected':'display-none'?>" id="writer">  <!--writer tab -->
    <div class="col-md-10 div-center text-center"><span class="float-left align-middle"><p class="dash-small-text margin-bottom-none">YOUR</p><h3 class="margin-top-none float-left">Current <br/>Balance</h3><p class="dash-small-text float-right margin-top-40 margin-left-min">IS</p></span><h2 class="margin-left-min text-blue float-left align-middle big-text margin-top-20">$<?php echo number_format($currentBalance); ?></h2>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('money/transfer')?>" class="btn-blue btn-small add-money margin-top-35">transfer</a><span>
        <a href="#"><img id="library1" src="<?php echo site_url('img/Transactions.png') ?>"></a></span>
    </div>


        <div class="text-center txt-green"><?php echo  validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo  $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php $inboxCount =0;
            if($inbox_messages)foreach($inbox_messages as $message){  if(!$message->is_read) $inboxCount++;} 
            ?>
                <ul class="tabs-menu2 div-center" role="tablist">
                    <li class="current2"><a href="#tab1">INBOX <?php echo 0<$unreadcount? '<span class="uc-notifications-bell__count js-uc-notifications-bell-count">'.$unreadcount.'</span>':''; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="<?php echo $dashboard_type=='ongoing'?'current2':' '?>"><a href="#tab2">ONGOING PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php echo $dashboard_type=='acceptpro'?'current2':' '?>"><a href="#tab3">ACCEPTED ARTICLES</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php echo $dashboard_type=='decpro'?'current2':' '?>"><a href="#tab4">DECLINED ARTICLES</a></li>
```

This is the tab structure for the above code. It keeps moving to the first tab from the second tab if you refresh the page or even when you submit a form on the second tab. This redirection has been stressing me quite a bit. If anyone could come up with a solution I would be grateful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabrow a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

The above code is the javascript to facilitate the flow of the tabs

I am posting the CSS below:

```
        .tabrow li.selected {
        background: #405b6c;
        color: #FFF;/*#333;*/
        z-index: 2;
        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    }
```

Comment: you have first li selected (class="selected") so when you submit and page reloads first li gets selected. what do we have in class selected?

Comment: please edit in your question not in comment

Comment: still not clear put more html code; the hierarchy of .tabrow a selector

Comment: can u put the css for .selected class